# CSS Responsive Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with my code.

I made a responsive page, and when I press a button to show/hide a div.
When the div is shown, that one hidden doesn't appear on the full-width page. 
Without jquery it works ok, but I need to show the info div when the button is pressed.

What to do ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function(e) {  
  if( $('#menu').text() == "SHOW INFO" )
  {
   $('#menu').text('HIDE INFO');
   
   $('#content').hide();
   $('#info').show();
  }
  else
  {
   $('#menu').text('SHOW INFO');
   $('#info').hide();
   $('#content').show();
  }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body 
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper
{
 background-color:white;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.menu 
{ 
 display:none; 
}

.content
{
 vertical-align: top;
 color:yellow;
 background-color:black;
 width:70%;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.info
{
 z-index:9999;
 background-color:white;
 width:29%;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
 word-wrap:break-word;
}

.infobox
{
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-right:30px;
 padding-top:30px;
 text-align:justify;
}

.spacer
{
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 height:1px;
 background-color:#D9D9D9;
}

.title
{
 font-size:16;
 font-family:Verdana;
}

.desc
{
 font-size:12px;
 font-family:Verdana;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) 
{ 
 .content
 {
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }

 .info 
 { 
  z-index:9999;
  width:100%;
  display:none; 
 }
 
 .menu
 {
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #D00355;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;     
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        transition: background 0.5s linear;
 }
 
 .menu:hover
 {
  background-color:#D00355;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        transition: background 0.5s linear;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Responsive Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimumscale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

 <div id="content" name="content" class="content">
  1
 </div>
 
 <div id="info" name="info" class="info">
  <div class="infobox">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="desc">asdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadadaasdadadada</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="menu" id="menu" name="menu">SHOW INFO</div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unable to understand your question , can you explain your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o37qrugw/ looks like your code works for me. If not, try to explain your problem better

Comment: yes, the code works. the problem appears when i minimize the window and i press SHOW INFO, the INFO div is shown, but when i maximize the window, the content div does not show.

Comment: example http://imgur.com/a/EvRWu ( the images are in order ) in the last pic, only the INFO div is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this issue is occurring is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .menu
    {
        display:block;
    }
}

.menu 
{ 
    display:none; 
}
```

So when the width of the screen crosses 700px, the media query doesn't work and normal css works which is setting the display property of the element to none.